# Ближайшее значение List<DateTime> через LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

прошу помочь составить Linq запрос

```
List<DateTime> j = new List<DateTime>();
```

в нем неизвестное кол-во елементов со значением дат. в формате "year-month-day"
нужно в новую переменную вытащить дату наиболее близкую к сегодняшней.

тоесть если в листе 
2018-11-30,
2018-12-01,
2018-12-02,

то должно вытянуть 2018-12-2

Comment: А даты могут быть по обе стороны от текущей? *в нем неизвестное кол-во елементов со значением дат. в формате "year-month-day"* – нет, даты в DateTime хранятся в специальном формате (в виде 64-битного числа), а выводить на экран их можно как угодно, следует это понимать

Comment: `2018-13-02` - это что за дата такая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что что-то типа этого:

```
List<DateTime> j = new List<DateTime>();
var nowDate=DateTime.Now;
j.Select(date => new {Secs = Math.Abs((nowDate - date).TotalSeconds), Date = date})
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Secs).First();
```

**Логика**

Я вычитаю из текущий даты, дату каждого элемента, а затем перевожу в секунды.

На основании этого я делаю анонимный класс Secs-секунды и Date-DateTime из вашего списка.

Далее, я сортирую по секундам по возрастанию. Очевидно, что элемент, где меньше всего секунд и будет нужным нам элементом. Так как мы выполнили сортировку, то он должен быть первым.

А возвращает 2 значения из-за того, что был создан анонимный класс с вспомогательным полем по которому мы выполнили сортировку. Можно просто взять элемент DateTime и присвоить в другую переменную.

Как альтернативный вариант, можно сделать так:

```
 List<DateTime> j = new List<DateTime>();
 var nowDate=DateTime.Now;
j.OrderBy(date => Math.Abs((nowDate - date).TotalSeconds)).First();
```

Comment: да, вроде заработало.   вот только не пойму почему возвращает 2 значения date & secs .
а не могли бы вы росписать логику построения данного запроса?

Comment: Расписал. Возвращает 2 значения, так как это анонимный тип, который был создан для промежуточных действий.

Comment: Брать нужно не [Seconds](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan.seconds?view=netframework-4.7.2), а [TotalSeconds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 5):

Альтернативным решением может быть использование метода [Aggregate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__System_Func___1___2__), это позволит найти значение с минимальным отклонением за один проход.

Для этого нужно задать начальное состояние, в котором хранить выбранную дату и ее разницу с Now.

```
new { Diff = TimeSpan.MaxValue, Date = new DateTime(0) }
```

В самом методе необходимо вычислить разницу между текущим элементом и `Now`, и получить ее абсолютное значение. Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`.Duration`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.duration?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var diff = (cur - now).Duration();
```

Если полученная разница больше сохраненной, вернуть сохраненную, если меньше - вернуть новую.

```
return (diff <= acc.Diff) ? new { Diff = diff, Date = cur } : acc
```

Чтобы в результате получить только дату, нужно добавить третий параметр, который показывает как определять результат, в данном случае нужно просто вернуть поле `Date`

```
acc => acc.Date
```

Все в сборе может выглядеть так:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var result = j.Aggregate(new { Diff = TimeSpan.MaxValue, Date = new DateTime(0) }, (acc, cur) =>
  {
      var diff = (cur - now).Duration();
      return (diff <= acc.Diff) ? new { Diff = diff, Date = cur } : acc
  }, acc => acc.Date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть популярная библиотека MoreLinq, с большим набором методов расширений. Предлагаю воспользоваться ей: решение будет лаконичным и понятным.

```
using MoreLinq;


var now = DateTime.Now;
var near = j.MinBy(date => Math.Abs((now - date).Ticks)).First();
```

По сути это тот же алгоритм, что в ответе **iluxa1810**.
И я думаю, что лучше использовать целочисленное свойство `Ticks`.

Comment: Не, алгоритм тут скорее как в моем ответе: происходит только один проход, а не сортировка. Просто дополнительно сохраняются все одинаковые значения максимума или минимума

Answer (score 1):

```
     var now = DateTime.Now;
     j.Aggregate(DateTime.MaxValue, (acc, next) => {
        var prevDiff = Math.Abs((now - acc).TotalHours);
        var currentDiff = Math.Abs((now - next).TotalHours);

        return prevDiff <= currentDiff ? acc : next;
      });
```